# delete or clear session in symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, session, symfony4

I am saving the current user s data in a session, I am using Symfony 4.4
I am getting and setting the data to the session variable this way

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('user', $user);
```

is there any way to clear and delete the session after logging out
I tried

```
$session->invalidate();
```

and deleting the session one by using remove and nothing happened

```
$session->remove('user');
```

Comment: Symfony already provides a way to get the current user and takes care of the logging out process.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: actually, it's a school project and our tutors are limiting our use of bundles like fosuser etc so we got to implement some functionalities from scratch

Comment: Looks like you got something working but just to be clear the get user functionality is in the Symfony framework.  Unless your instructor is not letting you use the SecurityBundle.  Which would actually be a good training approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i randomly came across this and it works just fine

```
$this->get('session')->clear();
```